# How to recoever after executing rm -f /bin/su; rm -f /usr/bin/sudo (with correct privileges)?

Tags: sudo, system-recovery

**This is a theoretical question.** What if I run those commands with correct privileges? How could I restore su and sudo?

Comment: If you deliberately cut off all your paths to root privileges, sometimes the only way to recover is to boot a rescue system and/or even reinstall.

Comment: Reinstall is the most obvious solution to just about everything.

Comment: It's easy to give an answer that starts with "Login as root, then ..." but distros that follow the sudo / su approach to managing things usually disable / disdain the direct login as root. And all other things that normally do root stuff (the package manager frontend) usually use these under the hood instead of packing their own suid root binaries (it's a security hazard). Of course, it doesn't hurt to check all suid binaries on the system anyhow.

Comment: @frostschutz But they do not disable `init=/bin/bash`

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think it would be a useful question to ask oneself. *How can I get in?*. Personal story: some years ago I forgot the keys to my summer home in my home town, 300 km distant. The spare keys were *inside* the home. Desperation was enough that I came up with a nondestructive way of *burgling the house and fetching the keys*, a way *that had been available to any observant burglar for the three years past*. In those three years I had been lucky.

Comment: @HaukeLaging They don't need to disable it. It's automatically disabled once you use initramfs. But of course the initramfs or init system may choose to deliberately re-implement the same functionality. While speaking of initramfs, it might have its own criteria for dumping you to a root shell. But some people strive to prevent those too ( silly example  http://hmarco.org/bugs/CVE-2016-4484/CVE-2016-4484_cryptsetup_initrd_shell.html ).

Comment: @frostschutz Interesting, I never thought about that. I guess that means that `/bin/bash` in the initrd is not bash (or at least one that does not become interactive). Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these binaries are required to *reinstall* the packages - so you simply need to gain root access and reinstall the packages containing those binaries with `apt`, `yum` or what ever package manager your system uses - there should be no need to do anything more dramatic then that.

The trick is gaining root access. This is trivial if the root account is unlocked and you know the password (which if you were using `su` then you do). At which point just log into the system as root and reinstall the packages.

If you do not have root access then you can try to reboot into recovery mode if your distro has that enabled - if so it will give you a root prompt which you can reinstall the required packages.

If you cannot get recovery mode to work or it is not enabled then you need to boot a live cd. Once booted with a live cd you can mount the root filesystem of your system somewhere, chroot into it and reinstall the packages that way. Such as:

```
cd /location/of/new/root
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount --rbind /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/

cp /etc/resolv.conf etc/resolv.conf

chroot /location/of/new/root /bin/bash

# <install packages here>
```

Answer (score 2):

Log onto console as root, `scp` the `/bin/su` and `/usr/bin/sudo` from a "known, good" neighboring server.

Comment: And how to do that? This is the first time I heard of `scp` and a quick looking at its manpage doesn't explain it to me.

Comment: @WeylynSavan If this is the first time you heard of `scp` then you probably should not bother with this kind of theoretical problems anyway.

Comment: Okay. I was just curious, because Joel Lee, who written '9 Lethal Linux Commands You Should Never Run' forgot to mention how to fix the system if someone was dumb enough to run any of those commands. At least in case, there's something left to fix. Unlike after mv / /dev/null or command > /dev/hda.

Answer (score 1):

If root access is available via SSH, then restore the binaries from another server (or upload the two files from the latest backup - **you did backup your system, didn't you?** - on any suitable server and download them from there):

```
ssh root@woundedserver "cd /usr/bin; wget http://myamazonserver/files/su; chmod 4755 su"

or

scp /usr/bin/su root@woundedserver:/usr/bin
# I never remember whether scp preserves permissions, so just to be sure:
ssh root@woundedserver "chmod 4755 /usr/bin/su"

or even (I just tried, the md5sums match after the copy)
cat /a/good/su/binary | ssh root@woundedserver "cat >/usr/bin/su; chmod 4755 /usr/bin/su"
```

If root isn't allowed to SSH in, or you disabled that possibility or closed the SSH port too, I suspect the only way is booting with the init "hack", or boot from a rescue CD. *That* ought to work.

If you *also* secured GRUB and maybe encrypted the filesystem, either wait for an exploitable vulnerability to be discovered, or reinstall everything from the latest backup. **You did backup your system, didn't you?** :-)

Comment: Backup? What is a 'backup'? :-)

Comment: In my native language I could make a lewd pun, but let's say it's the thing that *saves your back* :-) -- and saved mine, more times than I choose to remember - *shudder*

Comment: Of course, I know what it is. But let's pretend like most users, I don't have one either. Now what? Would downloading sudo's deb from the repo and installing it "somehow" work?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. To be safe, you would need the same distribution, then you would upload with any tool available.

Comment: Well just before rebooting for e.g. the initrd "hack", I can open any installed browser and google on package sudo _distro\_codename_, and download the one with the correct architecture. After "hacking" into my own system, I can simply install it with `dpkg -i`.